# JsFunction.apply doesn't work while JsObject.callMethod does work (dart)

Tags: javascript, dart, dart-js-interop

I have this often, that JsFunction.apply doesn't work like I would expect. Consider this example:

```
import "dart:js";
import "dart:html";

void main() {
  var div = querySelector('div');
  var span = new SpanElement()..text = "hello world";
  var js = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(div);
  js["appendChild"].apply([span]);

  // this one does work:
  // js.callMethod("appendChild", [span]);
}
```

I would expect that `js["appendChild"].apply([span]);` to work exactly the same as `js.callMethod("appendChild", [span]);`.

See also this demo: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/0f35d76a3c61ba1371f1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works with `js["appendChild"].apply([span], thisArg: js);`

If you don't provide `thisArg` it's like you call [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/apply) with `null` as first argument.

Thus your Dart call is the same as the js :

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerText = "hello world";
div["appendChild"].apply(null, [span]);
```

The execution of above js code leads to a `TypeError: Illegal invocation`. To make it work you have to use `div["appendChild"].apply(div, [span]);`.

So it was not a Dart issue but rather a js issue.